# Whats the protocol to unpair Mi Band 1s? (HCI command)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hci, xiaomi

I'm developing an app that uses Mi Band 1s to track Heart Rate. For now I achieved the pairing (with authentication). But I can't figure how to unpair the Mi Band.

Code the unpairing of the Mi Band is not my first priority, but I would like to do that with my app instead of going to MiFit pair the mi Band and unpair it every time I want to perform a pairing (with the auth motor) with my app.

Here you have the [app](https://github.com/arracso/HeartRate) and the [protocol](https://github.com/arracso/HeartRate/blob/master/app/src/main/java/edu/udg/exit/heartrate/MiBand/MiBandConstants.java) I searched/figured/etc.

I use the following sequence to do my initialization:

```
private void initialize() {
    // Enable notifications
    addCall(enableNotifications());

    // Set low latency to do a faster initialization
    addCall(setLowLatency());

    // Reading date for stability - TODO - Check if this is really necessary
    addCall(requestDate());

    // Authentication
    addCall(pair());
    addCall(requestDeviceInformation()); // Needed to send user info to the device
    addCall(requestDeviceName());
    addCall(sendUserInfo()); // Needed to authenticate
    addCall(checkAuthentication()); // Clear the queue when not authenticated

    // Other Initializations
    addCall(sendCommand(COMMAND.SET_WEAR_LOCATION_RIGHT)); // Set wear location // TODO - Check
    addCall(setHeartRateSleepSupport()); // TODO - Check
    addCall(setFitnessGoal(1000)); // TODO - Check and set fitness by the app

    // Enable other notifications // TODO - Check
    addCall(enableNotificationsFrom(UUID_CHAR.REALTIME_STEPS));
    addCall(enableNotificationsFrom(UUID_CHAR.ACTIVITY_DATA));
    addCall(enableNotificationsFrom(UUID_CHAR.BATTERY));
    addCall(enableNotificationsFrom(UUID_CHAR.SENSOR_DATA));

    // Enable Heart Rate notifications
    addCall(enableHeartRateNotifications());

    // Other Initializations
    addCall(setCurrentDate());
    addCall(requestBattery());

    // Set high latency to get an stable connection
    addCall(setHighLatency());

    // Finish initialization - device is ready to make other calls
    //addCall(setInitialized()); // TODO
}
```

As you can see there are still some calls that I have to check if they are really doing what they say. But for the moment it seems to be working. I would appreciate any other comments (not only about how to unpair).

**EDIT**

I started to capture the bluetooth packets of the oficial application and my application (I also mapped all handlers with its uuid, even if I don't known what characteristic is).

Ok, so, this is the capture of the disconnection from MiFit:

[image]

As you can see the host only send 4 packets to the band:

- Two of them are ATT packets to read steps and to dissable steps notifications.
- The other two are HCI commands.

I think I just have to send the second HCI command (first one is already sended when I call disconnect() or close()). The problem is that I don't know how to send that command.